# Plurals for questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, plurals

Sorry if this has already been discussed but I was just having a look at my profile on Stack Overflow and noticed that noticed that in the "Votes Cast" section at the bottom under "by type", should there not be an "s" after the words "question" and "answer" as shown in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an implied "votes" after each word there:

- 148 up [votes]
- 5 down [votes]
- 66 question [votes]
- 87 answer [votes]

Comment: ahh fair enough then...thanks :)